# Using registerSeekCallback() to do seek operation in Spring Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have `org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` with N MessageListeners listening to N partitions of a topic. Sometimes the application needs to start at an offset different from last committed offset.
I made the listener to be `ConsumerSeekAware` and using `registerSeekCallback()`. Resetting to different offset is only needed when the application starts, not when it is running, so I don't need to store the callback that is given by `registerSeekCallback()`.
As per the documentation, this `registerSeekCallback()` is invoked automatically when the listener container is started. So I'm going to invoke `callback.seek(topic,partition,offset)` method inside the `registerSeekCallback` method.

Question is, how can I get the *partition* which is assigned to the listener? seek method needs topic, partition, and offset as its arguments. Since partitions are assigned at runtime, I don't know how to get the right partition number to do seek operattion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`registerSeekCallback` is used to arbitrarily seek at runtime (any time after the container has started and partitions assigned).

Instead, you should do the seek in `ConsumerSeekAware.onPartitionsAssigned()` which will give you the partitions.

Comment: is registerSeekCallback() being called by spring before partition allocation or after?

Comment: It's called during initialization to give you a way to seek later (on the listener thread). You need to do the seek in `onPartitionsAssigned()`.